# Position div at bottom of containing div

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

I am having issues placing my dT(Date/Time) div at the bottom of it's containing div. I have tried setting `bottom: 0px;` to no avail. Below is the html and css code I am using.

HTML:

```
      <div class='container'>
          <aside>
              <img id="user-pic" src="images/blank-user.jpg">
              <a href="#">@User_Name</a>
              <div id="trend"><h6>TRENDING</h6></div>

          </aside>
          <section class="main">
          </section>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #dT{
        width:inherit;
        bottom: 0px;
        border-top: gray;
        background-color: gray;
        font-size: small;
    }
.container{
    margin-top: 80px;
}
section{
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    clear: left;
    top: 100px;

}
.tweet{
    width: 450px;
    height: 225px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 4px solid #F1433F;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 25px 15px 0px 15px;
}
.tweetContent{
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    margin: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
    border-top: 1px solid #EEEEEE;
}
```

There is some JQuery elements within my code that I have not poseted because I do not believe it would have any effect on the positioning of a div.

It appears that the jquery aspect of the code might have something to do with it so here it is.

UPDATE: removed JQuery because it was not relevant.

Comment: where is `#dt` in your html markup?

Comment: It is created using jQuery, so it is within the `<script>` tag

Comment: can you share the markup how it will look like once it is added?

Comment: Answer has been updated. Check now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position:relative` to parent of your `#dT` element . Only if it is relative you can control the child elements using `left` , `right` , `bottom` and `top`.

**Update:** 
And to the child elements for which you want to change position using `left` add `position:absolute`

P.S : Need to add `relative` for the div that contains #dT and `absolute` for #dT

```
#parentofdT
{
position:relative;
}

#dT
{
position:absolute
}
```

Comment: `position:relative;` doesn't fix it.

Comment: Answer has been updated. Got confused with the div names. @dlf85

Answer (score 1):

Easily pixed with `position:absolute;`: https://jsfiddle.net/1Lsnjou9/

Good luck.

Comment: It seems this doesn't work. #dT is being created by JQuery within a while loop so when it is called each new content box recieves a date/time. for some reason when I use `position:absolute` it only creates one #dt div and places it in the middle of my page...

Comment: Well then please add your jQuery and I'll update my answer. But take into account that the question wasn't a good answer candidate if you didn't include the jQuery.

Comment: In my initial post I mentioned that I didn't believe the JQuery was necessary, I was mistaken and have updated my code. Please keep in mind that I am a beginner so I was not aware that it would have an effect on my outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should add position: relative or position: absolute property to make the bottom: 0px work

```
 #dT{
        width:inherit;
        bottom: 0px;
        border-top: gray;
        background-color: gray;
        font-size: small;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: Wrong, he needs position:absolute; as far as I know?

Answer (score 0):

use position property like position absolute or position relative so as to work with top, left,right,bottom properties